# If Cramér's is proved?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Harald Cramér proved that under this assumption that the Riemann hypothesis is true., the gap $g_n$ satisfies $$g_n = O(\sqrt{p_n} \ln p_n)
,$$

using the big O notation. Later, he conjectured that the gaps are even smaller. Roughly speaking he conjectured that $$g_n = O\left((\ln p_n)^2\right).$$

Would the Riemann hypothesis be true if the $(\ln p_n)^2$ conjecture was proven true? (I know the proof will not happens soon. But, if it does?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that a proof of the Cramér conjecture would imply RH.

Comment: Don't believe, why? What is the disconnect?

Comment: @user160140: RH does imply somewhat short gaps between primes, but it requires that they are in a certain place (with regard to Li). Cramér says that the gaps are very short but doesn't care where they are. So although related, they're not obviously implicational. Of course the biggest piece of information is simply that, if such a result were known, it would be famous enough that I would know it. :)

Comment: So, I am taking a guess here. RH has implications with both size of gap and location of primes?

Comment: @user160140: Yes. The primes must be within $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ of Li(x) and the gaps, consequently, can't be larger than $O(\sqrt x\log x)$.

Comment: So the RH shows were on Li(x) within $O(\sqrt x\log x)$, which is $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ < $O((\log x)^2$, and there is not a inverse of Li(x) as to find where the zeros are on the $i$-plane?

Comment: @user160140: I can't make sense of what you wrote. Certainly $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ can be much, much bigger than $O((\log x)^2)$, and I didn't say anything about $i$ or the inverse of Li.

Comment: So, the RH shows were a prime should be on $Li(x)$ within $O(\sqrt x\log x)$, which is $O(\sqrt x\log x) < O((\log x)^2$? And, is there not a inverse of $Li(x)$ as to find where the zeros are on the i-plane? I have read something about the zeros at $\Re(s)=1/2$ being used to find primes some how. I guess the real axis is scaled to $Li(x)$?

Comment: @user160140: There *is* an inverse of Li, at least on the real numbers greater than (say) 2. And $O(\sqrt x\log x)<O((\log x)^2)$ is certainly false. So no, I don't agree. On the other hand there is a version (the usual version) of RH which is about the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, in particular that if $s$ is not purely real then $\zeta(s)=0\Rightarrow\Re(s)=1/2.$

Comment: Opps, yes, $O(\sqrt x\log x) > O((\log x)^2)$. I did not catch that I wrote that that way and when I copied it. I that means to me that the error of RH is much greater than the error of the error of $O((\log x)^2)$ A version, how many versions are there? And, am I switching the and not knowing it?

Comment: Many statements are equivalent to RH, the one with Re(s) = 1/2 is the usual one. Yes, the error of RH in the $\pi(x)$ version is much greater than the Cramér error.